# Index of maximum value of a list

Tags: python

I need to implement a function that returns the index of the maximum value of a list. I wrote that but it doesn't work. Could someone tell me why?

```
def maximum_index(lst):
    maximum=0
    index=0
    for i,value in enumerate(lst):
        if value>maximum:
            maximum=value
            index=i
    return index
```

Comment: It also should return None when the list is empty but I'm not sure how to do it

Comment: start with `if not lst: return None`

Comment: your current method fails if the maximum value is <0

Comment: As it was already mentionned on your previous question on SO, 'it doesn't work' is not an accurate enough description of the problem your encountered. If you get an error, please include the complete error traceback. If you don't get the expected result for some data, include the relevant data that exhibits the faulty behavior, as well as the output you get vs the expected one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seemed fine to me. I think the only problem is your indentation and that you only check positive values. The way it is indented everything is outside of the function.

Also I added Chris_Rands suggestion of starting with a check, whether the list is empty. Here you go:

```
def maximum_index(lst):
    if not lst: 
        return None

    first = True
    maximum=0
    index=0
    for i,value in enumerate(lst):
        if value > maximum or first:
            first = False
            maximum = value
            index = i
    return index
```

Comment: This still fails if the maximum is < 0

Comment: Yeah, I oversaw that as well. Made an edit to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) built-in function to find the maximum value and [index](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method to find its index:

```
def maximum_index(lst):
  if (not lst):
    return None
  return lst.index(max(lst))
```

Test it:

```
print(maximum_index([1, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 6]))
print(maximum_index([]))
```

Output:

```
3
None
```

Answer (score 0):

a better way is to just use max directly:

```
max(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: pair[1], default=(None, None))[0]
```

`enumerate` yields `(idx, value)` tuples for the list, the `key` checks for the max based on only the `value`, and then `[0]` grabs the `idx` from the tuple from `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't allowed to use `max` and `index` as suggested by @Ayxan, you should start the loop assuming that the first element *is* the max, and then updating accordingly.

```
def maximum_index(lst):
    if not lst:  # check if list is empty
        return None

    # initialize maximum and index
    index = None
    maximum = lst[0]

    # loop and update
    for i, value in enumerate(lst):
        if value > maximum:
            maximum = value
            index = i

    # return index
    return index


alist = [5, 6, 1, 199, -1, 0, 12]
print(maximum_index(alist))
print(maximum_index([]))
```